# Extracting a byte portability in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, byte

I found the following snippet in the library that I'm using:

```
/* extract a byte portably */
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define byte(x, n) ((unsigned char)((x) >> (8 * (n))))
#else
#define byte(x, n) (((x) >> (8 * (n))) & 255)
#endif
```

This is only for use with unsigned types. Why doesn't the second form work with MSVC?

I'm adapting some of the code and would like to replace the above with an inline function, but I don't want to stop it working with MSVC.

Comment: The two definitions are not equivalent - they produce expressions of different types. That could matter in overload resolution, among other contexts: e.g. `std::cout << byte(12345, 1)` would do different things under different definitions. In any case, both [appear to work for me](http://rextester.com/CTPW47876) with MSVC - what makes you believe one of them doesn't?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I couldn't find any indication of why the library author put that MSVC-specific code in. I don't like having `#ifdef`s in my code unless they are really, really necessary, so wanted the rationale.

Comment: Have you considered asking the author? No one else would be able to tell you what went through their head when they wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

> ... and would like to replace the above with an inline function -- but I don't want to stop it working with MSVC.)

Did you mean something like

```
/* extract a byte portably */
template<typename T>
inline unsigned char byte(T x, size_t n) 
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    { return ((unsigned char)((x) >> (8 * (n)))); }
#else
    { return (((x) >> (8 * (n))) & 255); }
#endif
```

?

I can't actually tell why the second part doesn't work with MSVC, though as demonstrated above you can still support both with an `inlined` function.

---

Note: Some compilers or 3rd party library already have a `byte` macro or `typedef` defined and may screw up your inline function definition. You might better use a different function name like `extract_byte` or such.